# Chinese google maps in Android

Tags: android, mapping, native

Apparently, using Google Mapping natively in Android (`MapView` with an API key etc.) doesn't work for users in China. However, recently [maps.google.cn](http://maps.google.cn) has become unblocked (Q1 2018: [Websites blocked in mainland China](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Websites_blocked_in_mainland_China))

Does anyone know of a way to adapt a native Android App to use [maps.google.cn](http://maps.google.cn) if the user is in China?

Does Google provide an alternative API key for this map server? If so, I haven't found it...

I've considered, on Locale detection, swapping out my `MapView` with a `WebView` showing maps.google.cn, but it seems a lot of hassle to get the same functionality and marker placement/selection etc. with JavaScript.

I've considered Baidu and Gaode, which provide mapping for China, but the API key registration isn't clear (or in a language I understand), seems to require a local phone number which I don't have, and I'm wary of signing up for stuff I can't read clearly. There are also coordinate conversion overheads - all in all, a bit of a pain.